# Running time of Binary Search using Python plots

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, plot, binary-search

How can we find the running time of binary search using python plots.
I tried to get recursion of binary search with my code below but I am not sure how to plot.

```
    if higher >= lower:
 
        middle = (higher + lower) // 2
        if array[middle] == x:
            return middle
        elif array[middle] > x:
            return binary_search(array, lower, middle - 1, x)
 
        else:
            return binary_search(array, middle + 1, higher, x)
 
    else:
        return -1
 
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 20 ]
x = 10
 

result = binary_search(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, x)
print(result)



Thanks
```

Comment: _What_ exactly are you trying to plot?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur - Actually I want to find the run time complexity of binary search with increase in input. I.e Log n. And want to plot input vs time plot for this.

Comment: How would you plot this for a single run? Do you have multiple inputs over which you'll test performance?